# Why would calling procedures one after the other slow the processing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some .docx templates and do find and replace.

When completed, I start the next .docx template.

When I do find and replace on one template it's very quick (<10sec.).

When I do multiple templates after each other it's not that quick. Let's say I'm doing 10 templates. It not equals 10 * 10sec.

How this is possible?

```
If Worksheets("Project Gegevens").Range("B2").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Nederlands" Then
    Call Module003_Voorkant_NL.Voorkant_NL
    Call Module004_Zijkant_NL.Zijkant_NL
    Call Module005_Dagverslag_NL.Dagverslag_NL
    Call Module006_Todo_NL.Todo_NL
    Call Module007_FAT_NL.FAT_NL
    Call Module008_HMI_NL.HMI_NL
    Call Module009_Project_Data_NL.Project_Data_NL
    Call Module010_Standaard_Vragen_NL.Standaard_Vragen_NL
    Call Module011_Index_12_Tabs_NL.Index_12_Tabs_NL
    Call Module012_Kastenbouw_NL.Kastenbouw_NL
    Call Module013_Man_Dec_NL.Man_Dec_NL
ElseIf Worksheets("Project Gegevens").Range("B2").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Engels" Then

ElseIf Worksheets("Project Gegevens").Range("B2").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Duits" Then

Else
End If
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what each procedure call is doing.  Referencing sheets and cells slows it down to - better to pull all data into the VBA environment in as few steps as possible and then work on it there.  `.Offset(0,0)` isn't doing anything - you could just write `Range("B2") = "Nederlands"` (`Value` is the default property).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you very much! Next question: I want to know if this is the most efficient way to call different modules, as wel as going back. I have no call from the to be called modules to this current module. Is a "End Sub" in the to be called module the most efficient way to jump back and  perform the next call?

Comment: You could just write `Voorkant_NL` instead of `Call Module003_Voorkant_NL.Voorkant_NL`.  I don't understand your second question - a procedure must end with `End Sub` and when a procedure ends it will jump back to wherever it was called from.  The speed issue depends on what's going on within your procedures - for example you may be opening another workbook within one procedure and closing it, the next procedure then reopens the same workbook.... would be faster to just pass the workbook reference from one to the other.  There's nothing inherently slow with the code you've posted.

Comment: If you're opening Word documents does each procedure create an instance of Word or do you just open it once and then refer to the same instance throughout?  Is your code littered with lots of `Select`, `Active`, `Selection` commands which will slow things down?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook First of all; Thank you very much for your answers! I do:

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")

wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Cur_dir_var & "\!Voorkant map template (Nederlands).docx")
For Each wdRng In wdDoc.StoryRanges
    With wdRng.Find

After this I'm search and replace for some tags.

Comment: But do you do that in each procedure, or share the reference between all procedures?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I do this in each procedure

Comment: That's one place you could speed things up then - just create the instance once and either store it as a global variable, or pass it as an argument to each procedure that needs it.